# How are table headers supposed to be used?

Tags: html

Recently I saw some code like this:

```
<tr> 
     <th> Some label: </th>
     <td> <input type="text" value=""/> </td>
     <th> Another label: </th>
     <td> <input type="text" value=""/> </td>
</tr>
```

I am used to table headers being used like

```
<tr> 
     <th> Some label: </th>
     <th> Another label: </th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td> <input type="text" value=""/> </td>
     <td> <input type="text" value=""/> </td>
</tr>
```

How are table headers supposed to be used? The first example above, lead me to some pretty funky formatting issues, and it seems like in example 1 `<label>` should be used in place of `<th>`.

Comment: That basic problem here is that tables shouldn't be used to layout forms.

Comment: Tables are for displaying tabular data, not for positioning the layout of elements.  The latter is considered bad styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of them is correct. A header is used to provide the header for a table and not as a layout mechanism for form fields. As you mentioned I would use `<label>`. Tables should be used to present tabular data.

I am assuming that you copied the example to show how a `<th>` is actually used and don't intend to use it for layout purposes. If that is the case then you are correct in your structuring and would recommend adding `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements like so:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Heading 1</th>
         <th>Heading 2</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 1 Col 1 Data</td>
         <td>Row 1 Col 2 Data</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 2 Col 1 Data</td>
         <td>Row 2 Col 2 Data</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

One advantage for this is that if your page spans multiple pages when you print it, the header will show up automatically on each page.

Note that there is aslo a `<tfoot>` element that you can use.

Comment: Thanks and yes the example I showed was to show how I thought th elements were supposed to be used. Unfortunately for me, I'm working on someone else's code, where they used a table to layout 50 plus input fields :(.

Comment: @stevebot There is no way to sugarcoat it, but it sounds like web development hell. Nothing a little CSS and some restructuring wouldn't fix. Anyway, 50 plus input fields on a page seems like it needs a little UX love to make it increase the usability.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the `th` elements [should be in their own `tr` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6).  And I agree that the first example should instead call for `label` elements.  (Well, *both* examples call for something other than tables to be used entirely, but that's not the meat of the question.)

Answer (score 0):

In your first example labels and input-fields will be in the same row. 
This is not how `<TH>` was supposed to be used. In the second example you have the headers in their own row above the input fields. You certainly need to add `<table>` and `</table>`.